# How to determine the parameters of a maven plugin at runtime

Tags: maven, parameters, maven-plugin

I wrote a plugin to build PDF from latex sources.
There is another tool doing this, `latexmk`, which is more interactive
whereas my tool is more used at the end of the process.

What I want to do is, I want to pass my parameters to the config file `.latexmkrc` of `latexmk`.
This is to keep the settings of the two tools synchronized.

My idea was to do something like filtering:
Have a raw `.latexmkrc` file with texts `${parameterName}`
representing a parameter `parameterName`
and then doing a kind of maven like filtering, replacing the parameter
defined by

```
@Parameter(name="parameterName")
private int someIntParameter;
```

by the value of `someIntParameter`.

The sole problem is that `@Parameter` has retention `class`,
which means that at runtime the `@Parameter` annotation is no longer visible.

How to solve that problem?

I am aware I could just use all field names, no matter whether parameters or not and replace `${someFieldName}`
by the value of the field `someFieldName`, but I feel this is not quite clean.

Maybe I dont have enough understanding of annotations and retention.
How to access annotations with class retention at all?
Must be stored in the class file but at runtime not accessible...
When does it disappear? class loading?
And how to extract at all????